# How to check if path in firebase is there( check if child is there ) flutter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I would like to check if path like ( database.reference().child('classData') ) is there . and if it's not there I would like to return null

I tried
`(database.reference().child('classData') == null )` in if statement nothing happens.

Comment: Just perform a normal read on that location and check the value, if null this means it doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `database.reference().child('classData')` statement merely creates a path to a location in the database. It does not trigger a read of the data at that path, so it can't be used to check if data exists at the location.

To determine if data exists, read the data from the database, for example with a `once()` as shown in this [example from the FlutterFire repo](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/example/lib/main.dart#L62-L64):

> ```
> _messagesRef = database.reference().child('messages');
> database.reference().child('counter').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
>   print('Connected to second database and read ${snapshot.value}');
> });
> ```

Then check the `value` of the [`DataSnapshot`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot-class.html).

Comment: the read once never gets updated if I rerun it again do u know the cause?